# Filling a tableview with destination entities

Tags: ios, core-data, entity-relationship

I have a tableview which needs to show all the different destination entities from the different relationships. To keep it simple, let's look at one relationship, the one from the entity Operation to Goal, relationshipname: goal (inverse: operationalisation)

I'm wondering how to fill the cells

This is what I have:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
goals = [[NSArray alloc] init];
goals = [[self.operation valueForKeyPath:@"goal.goalNaam"] allObjects]  ;
}
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath       *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if(indexPath.section == 2){
        Goal *goal = (Goal*)[goals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = goal.goalNaam;
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Im wondering this is the way to do it. Simulator jams but is not giving an error..

Comment: Check in NSLog (@"GOAL: %@", goals); after goals = [[self.operation valueForKeyPath:@"goal.goalNaam"] allObjects]; look which result will return. And repeat this after Goal *goal = (Goal*)[goals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; In one of this NSlog result maybe null... Also, you exactly use indexPath.section == 2 not indexPath.row == 2? (this is just in case)

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this 2 NSLogs ? I can't follow.. And this section == 2 is not important. Filling only this section 2 with the Goals connected to the Operation. In another section I want another entity which is connected to Operation.

Comment: In log you can see correct or not information you get. If correct in your mean (example not null), so troubles in other place of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure you are using a 1:n relationship between Operation and Goal? I think I do not understand your question correctly. Shouldn't have one Operation multiple Goals and each goal has an attribute `goalNaam`? And if it would be like that, than the Operation model would contain a NSSet of associated `Goal` objects which could be retrieved easily.

Cheers,
anka

Comment: I'm using an n:n relationship between Operation and Goal. One Operation should (could) indeed have multiple Goals. And indeed, each goal has an attribute goalNaam. Then you probably mean the NSSet goal (relationship), yes but how do I implement this ? I copy the NSSet to an array?

Comment: Ok, just use the `goal` relationship which is an `NSSet` and you can get an Array by doing something like that: `NSArray *tmp = [operation.goal allObjects];` Then `tmp` contains all Goal objects of the operation.